# SQL UPDATE - INNER JOIN QUERY

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, inner-join, update-inner-join

I am trying to do an update in 2 tables, but i have this error:

> Error SQL: ORA-00933: "SQL command not properly ended".

Could you help me please? The query is:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.ACTORID_ = SUBSTR(a.ACTORID_, 2, LENGTH(a.ACTORID_)),
    b.TASKACTORID_ = SUBSTR(b.TASKACTORID_, 2, LENGTH(b.TASKACTORID_))
FROM jbpm_taskinstance AS a
    INNER JOIN jbpm_log AS b 
    ON b.TASKACTORID_ = a.ACTORID_
WHERE a.ACTORID_ = b.TASKACTORID_
     AND b.TASKINSTANCE_ IN (
          SELECT ID_ 
          FROM jbpm_taskinstance 
          WHERE a.PROCINST_ =b.PROCINST_)
     AND b.TASKACTORID_ = a.ACTORID_;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think questions that are shown in duplicate and this question seems different. OP wants to update two different tables in a single statement and the duplicate questions are updating one table using another table. If you agree then you can re-open it.

Comment: I have read all related questions, but i dont know where is the error.

Comment: how can i reopen @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: You can't use FROM or JOIN in an UPDATE statement and you can't update more than one table.

Comment: Please @a_horse_with_no_name could you reopne the question?

Comment: I have voted to re-open it. Let's see another answerers vote to re-open it or not!!

Comment: @AmaiaEspinosa . . . I would instead suggest that you delete this question.  Ask a *new* question with an explanation of what you want to accomplish along with sample data and desired results.  Don't make other people have to re-engineer what you want from broken SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of strange and misleading Oracle error messages!

With experience, you can spot the error by sight, as @a_horse_with_no_name has done.

If you don't see the error immediately, I'd recommend to make the query simpler step by step until the error disappears. In your case, I would remove the `AND b.taskinstance_ IN ()` subquery and check if the same error comes up. Then I'd remove the `SUBSTR` with a simple constant, like `SET a.ACTORID_ = 'a'`. Then I'd remove the `JOIN`, updating only table `A`. This will run ok, so you need to read up Oracle's documentation on `UPDATE`.